# The requested resource [/ords] is not available 404 not found

Tags: tomcat9, oracle-ords

I installed Oracle ORDS and TomCat on the server. When I go to the link with `host/ords` through browser, it gave me a 404 not found error. But when I remove `/ords`, it gave me a successful page telling me I have successfully installed TomCat. What caused this issue?

[Tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwIGI.png)
[404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gmdz.png)

Comment: What are you expecting to see at that url?

Comment: I'm expecting to see the login portal to Oracle Apex when I added /ords after host.

Comment: Then that should be noted in the question. During install did you configure the plsql gateway and supply the location for apex static files and images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I restarted TomCat in Services on server. ORDS is listening again.